# React Native Page Reload

Tags: react-native

I have a function which I want to execute at the time of page load. First Time it works fine but if I go to the same page again It will not call the function. I understand that my Page is cached. How will I trigger some function on page load every time.

Comment: You can use the component life-cycle method(like componentDidMount in your case).

Comment: componentDidMount will get called only once unless if you explicitly create another instance of your component

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you exactly mean by *page load*.
If you mean that a different component gets rendered and then our original component gets rendered again, then it is these functions:

1. `componentWillMount`
2. `render`
3. `componentDidMount`

If you mean that you put your app in the background and then in the foreground again, you might not be able to rely on the react lifecycle functions at all (if no props are passed).

But you can to register a function that detects `AppState` changes like this:

```
AppState.addEventListener('change', handleAppStateChange);

const handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState: AppStateStatus) => {
  switch (nextAppState) {
    case 'active':
      break;
    case 'background':
      break;
    default:
  }
};
```

That way you get a callback when you put your app (and thus your *Page* into foreground again)